# Modify Hashtables in the ST Monad

Tags: haskell, hashtable

So, I was looking for mutable hashtables (for speed reasons), and the [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058529/curious-about-hashtable-efficiency) from Don Stewart led me to try out [hashtables](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashtables-1.1.0.2).

Being a bit inexperienced in the ST Monad, I successfully expanded the [given example](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hashtables/1.1.0.2/doc/html/Data-HashTable-Class.html) to:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import qualified Data.HashTable.ST.Cuckoo as C
import qualified Data.HashTable.Class as H
import Control.Monad.ST.Safe
import Data.Text

type HashTable s k v = C.HashTable s k v

foo :: ST s (HashTable s Text Int)
foo = do
  ht <- H.newSized 1
  H.insert ht "abc" 1
  H.insert ht "dea" 3
  return ht

add1 :: HashTable s Text Int -> ST s (HashTable s Text Int)
add1 ht = do
  H.insert ht "abc" 2
  H.insert ht "dea" 4
  return ht

main = do
  let x = runST $ H.toList =<< foo
  print x
  let y = runST $ H.toList =<< add1 =<< foo
  print y
```

From my (limited) understanding it allows to operate on data structures in a mutable way, but then 'freeze them' and present the result in such a way that it can be escaped from, through `runST` - and thus we can use the `let` bindings, and not `<-`.

However, I was failing to see how I could operate on an hashtable without always converting it to/from lists. The following code does not even compile:

```
   -- does not compile
   let z = runST foo
   let w = runST $ add1 z
   print w
```

It gives the following error (among others):
hashtable.hs:31:19:

```
Couldn't match type `a' with `C.HashTable s Text Int'
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the inferred type of z :: a at hashtable01.hs:31:7
Expected type: ST s a
  Actual type: ST s (HashTable s Text Int)
In the second argument of `($)', namely `foo'
In the expression: runST $ foo
In an equation for `z': z = runST $ foo
```

This is probably due to the `s` constrain in the type, and my guess is that it's probably there for precisely that reason. If we would later use `z` it would not have the same value, since the `add1` operated in place, and thus it would not be pure. Is this correct?

But then, the ST Monad in this particular case is only useful for a situation where:

- You give a fixed input
- You calculate the new value based on it, using mutable data structures
- You freeze the result, making it imutable again.

Any further change requires a toList/fromList that efectively copies the values and keeps the original imutable. As I am writing this, I'm thinking - duh, this is the definition of a pure function, as used everywhere in haskell, and thus the use case for the ST Monad (have I reached ST enlightenment?)

So, i guess the real question in this case is: isn't this toList/fromList operation expensive (2xO(n)), and couldn't it there be another way to operate on a copy without the toList/fromList pair of functions. Or am I overcomplicating, and I should just use the IO version of Hashtables?

Comment: Please include all imports

Comment: Ah, sorry about that... I've included the missing imports.

Comment: I don't think `runST $ foo >>= add1` marshal toList/fromList. Basically you can compose all the ST moands and no marshalling will happen when you execute the composed ST monad

Comment: Yes, it's expensive, and the usual way of dealing with this is to pull everything else into the ST monad until you have a function which uses a hash table as an _internal_ implementation detail and doesn't expose that to the rest of the code.

Comment: AFAIK there's no `STArray`-like freezing for hashtables.

Comment: Louis and n.m., that was precisely my question. If either of you would make it an answer, I will mark it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that you can't operate on a hashtable once it leaves the `ST` monad. The answer is not to do `toList/fromList` marshaling, but instead to just have a single `runST` that scopes over *everything* you need to do with mutating that table.

I.e. as Louis wrote in the comments: "pull everything else into the ST monad until you have a function which uses a hash table as an internal implementation detail and doesn't expose that to the rest of the code".