# How to optimize this Haskell code summing up the primes in sublinear time?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, optimization, data-structures, primes

Problem 10 from [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net) is to find the sum of all the primes below given *n*.

I solved it simply by summing up the primes generated by the sieve of Eratosthenes. Then I came across much more efficient [solution by Lucy_Hedgehog](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1378286/find-the-sum-of-all-primes-smaller-than-a-big-number/2283829#2283829) (sub-linear!).

For *n = 2⋅10^9*:

- [Python code](https://gist.github.com/AdamStelmaszczyk/d46faa15ba0c6d1432fd1fcbf7cc8a85) (from the quote above) runs in 1.2 seconds in Python 2.7.3.
- [C++ code](https://gist.github.com/AdamStelmaszczyk/a6661e53e34bbf8b10af0fa5a5e97395) (mine) runs in about 0.3 seconds (compiled with g++ 4.8.4).

I re-implemented the same algorithm in Haskell, since I'm learning it:

```
import Data.List

import Data.Map (Map, (!))
import qualified Data.Map as Map

problem10 :: Integer -> Integer
problem10 n = (sieve (Map.fromList [(i, i * (i + 1) `div` 2 - 1) | i <- vs]) 2 r vs) ! n
              where vs = [n `div` i | i <- [1..r]] ++ reverse [1..n `div` r - 1]
                    r  = floor (sqrt (fromIntegral n))

sieve :: Map Integer Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> [Integer] -> Map Integer Integer
sieve m p r vs | p > r     = m
               | otherwise = sieve (if m ! p > m ! (p - 1) then update m vs p else m) (p + 1) r vs

update :: Map Integer Integer -> [Integer] -> Integer -> Map Integer Integer
update m vs p = foldl' decrease m (map (\v -> (v, sumOfSieved m v p)) (takeWhile (>= p*p) vs))

decrease :: Map Integer Integer -> (Integer, Integer) -> Map Integer Integer
decrease m (k, v) = Map.insertWith (flip (-)) k v m

sumOfSieved :: Map Integer Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
sumOfSieved m v p = p * (m ! (v `div` p) - m ! (p - 1))

main = print $ problem10 $ 2*10^9
```

I compiled it with `ghc -O2 10.hs` and run with `time ./10`.

It gives the correct answer, but takes about 7 seconds.

I compiled it with `ghc -prof -fprof-auto -rtsopts 10` and run with `./10 +RTS -p -h`.

[10.prof](https://gist.github.com/AdamStelmaszczyk/81c443191b25a73e868d56ae3cae0994) shows that `decrease` takes 52.2% time and 67.5% allocations.

After running `hp2ps 10.hp` I got such heap profile:

[image: hp]

Again looks like `decrease` takes most of the heap. GHC version 7.6.3.

How would you optimize run time of this Haskell code?

---

Update 13.06.17:

I [tried](https://gist.github.com/AdamStelmaszczyk/f9a5d156a752fbe6c71652866fed9770) replacing immutable `Data.Map` with mutable `Data.HashTable.IO.BasicHashTable` from the `hashtables` package, but I'm probably doing something bad, since for tiny *n = 30* it already takes too long, about 10 seconds. What's wrong?

Update 18.06.17:

[Curious about the HashTable performance issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058529/curious-about-the-hashtable-performance-issues) is a good read. I took Sherh's [code](https://gist.github.com/ChShersh/062b4322a76cb74ecf3edfa1fef08237) using mutable `Data.HashTable.ST.Linear`, but [dropped `Data.Judy` in instead](https://gist.github.com/AdamStelmaszczyk/acaa98e81cbdd088c8b7f0394b3ccf97). It runs in 1.1 seconds, still relatively slow.

Comment: Could you please split the algorithm up to reasonably sized top level functions which can be reasoned about (seing types, etc. helps...) ? Thanks.

Comment: Change `Map` to `IntMap`.

Comment: @Centril I factored out `sieve`, `update`, `decrease` and `sumOfsieved`, hope it helps.

Comment: How much of your algorithm is dominated by modifying Maps, and how much by reading? If you read a lot, then using http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.1/docs/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html is great for numeric code. There's also http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Thank you, I also changed `Integer` to `Int`, code [here](https://gist.github.com/AdamStelmaszczyk/52e3cf83322ac5f88aeb9e18dd068348). It brought run-time down to 5 seconds.

Comment: I wonder if using `Data.IntMap.Strict` would decrease the number of allocations; I suspect that subtraction in `insertWith` mostly generates thunks.

Comment: @Centril There are 2 loops there, outer one iterating through possible primes p and inner one iterating through sufficient "check-point" integers for DP. It may be easier to look into Python [code](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1378286/find-the-sum-of-all-primes-smaller-than-a-big-number/2283829#2283829) to see that. In the outer loop there are 5 reads (from keys `p`, `p - 1`, `p - 1` again, `v`, `v // p`) and 1 write, in the inner loop there 3 reads and 1 write. Thanks for the links, I'm looking into them.

Comment: @9000 I checked and it didn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've done some small improvements so it runs in `3.4-3.5` seconds on my machine.
Using `IntMap.Strict` helped a lot. Other than that I just manually performed some `ghc` optimizations just to be sure. And make Haskell code more close to Python code from your link. As a next step you could try to use some mutable `HashMap`. But I'm not sure... `IntMap` can't be much faster than some mutable container because it's an immutable one. Though I'm still surprised about it's efficiency. I hope this can be implemented faster.

Here is the code:

```
import Data.List (foldl')
import Data.IntMap.Strict (IntMap, (!))
import qualified Data.IntMap.Strict as IntMap

p :: Int -> Int
p n = (sieve (IntMap.fromList [(i, i * (i + 1) `div` 2 - 1) | i <- vs]) 2 r vs) ! n
               where vs = [n `div` i | i <- [1..r]] ++ [n', n' - 1 .. 1]
                     r  = floor (sqrt (fromIntegral n) :: Double)
                     n' = n `div` r - 1

sieve :: IntMap Int -> Int -> Int -> [Int] -> IntMap Int
sieve m' p' r vs = go m' p'
  where
    go m p | p > r               = m
           | m ! p > m ! (p - 1) = go (update m vs p) (p + 1)
           | otherwise           = go m (p + 1)

update :: IntMap Int -> [Int] -> Int -> IntMap Int
update s vs p = foldl' decrease s (takeWhile (>= p2) vs)
  where
    sp = s ! (p - 1)
    p2 = p * p
    sumOfSieved v = p * (s ! (v `div` p) - sp)
    decrease m  v = IntMap.adjust (subtract $ sumOfSieved v) v m

main :: IO ()
main = print $ p $ 2*10^(9 :: Int)
```

**UPDATE:**

Using mutable `hashtables` I've managed to make performance up to `~5.5sec` on Haskell with [this implementation](https://gist.github.com/ChShersh/062b4322a76cb74ecf3edfa1fef08237).

Also, I used unboxed vectors instead of lists in several places. `Linear` hashing seems to be the fastest. I think this can be done even faster. I noticed [`sse42` option](https://github.com/gregorycollins/hashtables/blob/7550c23b2f005af19b380625d78b669830130eb4/hashtables.cabal#L137) in `hasthables` package. Not sure I've managed to set it correctly but even without it runs that fast.

**UPDATE 2** (19.06.2017)

I've managed to make it `3x` faster then best solution from @Krom (using my code + his map) by dropping judy hashmap at all. Instead just plain arrays are used. You can come up with the same idea if you notice that keys for `S` hashmap are either sequence from `1` to `n'` or `n div i` for `i` from `1` to `r`. So we can represent such HashMap as two arrays making lookups in array depending on searching key.

***My code + Judy HashMap***

```
$ time ./judy
95673602693282040

real    0m0.590s
user    0m0.588s
sys     0m0.000s
```

***My code + my sparse map***

```
$ time ./sparse
95673602693282040

real    0m0.203s
user    0m0.196s
sys     0m0.004s
```

This can be done even faster if instead of `IOUArray` already generated vectors and `Vector` library is used and `readArray` is replaced by `unsafeRead`. But I don't think this should be done if only you're not really interested in optimizing this as much as possible.

Comparison with this solution is cheating and is not fair. I expect same ideas implemented in Python and C++ will be even faster. But @Krom solution with closed hashmap is already cheating because it uses custom data structure instead of standard one. At least you can see that standard and most popular hash maps in *Haskell* are not that fast. Using better algorithms and better ad-hoc data structures can be better for such problems.

[Here's resulting code.](https://gist.github.com/ChShersh/35df251f98874e2d6a868880b68f60fa)

Comment: Thanks, I checked timings on my machine. Using `Map.Strict` gave 4s. Using `IntMap.Strict` 3.2s. Didn't change the time: helper function `go` with less arguments, `sp`, no `if`, `subtract`, no `map`, no `reverse`. But the last 4 make the code more readable IMO, so it's great to know, thanks. [Code](https://gist.github.com/AdamStelmaszczyk/e0e794e6392dd7ff9758fc64d5557622). My feeling at the moment is that to get much better performance one needs to use mutable data structure. I'm reading about mutable vectors, however it looks like understanding monads/arrows will take me some time.

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk You could try to read this blog post. It might help you to come with imperative/mutable solution faster: https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/6e4wq8/imperative_haskell/

Comment: Thanks for the link, I updated my question. I [tried](https://gist.github.com/AdamStelmaszczyk/f9a5d156a752fbe6c71652866fed9770) using mutable `BasicHashTable`, but I'm probably doing something wrong, since it's very slow...

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk I've updated answer with mutable version with runs rather fast. Just directly translated Python code from your link.

Comment: If I try your updated program it gives me a wrong result of `318504960`

Comment: @Krom Yes, you're right :( I was in hurry and forgot to subtract result. Now implementation works correctly. But runs `5.5sec` instead. This is because extra lookup in hashtable in most inner loop. If instead `update` function was used (which is, unfortunately, not implemented for hashtable) then I think this can be done faster. I'll try to implement `update` function manually later.

Comment: I plugged my hashmap into your code, see [here](https://gist.github.com/erwo42/a455a80bfe1dac6203204665b71d48b6) with that it runs in 0.6 seconds on my machine.

Comment: @Krom Nice! That's already faster than python implementation.

Comment: I didn't test the python solution on my machine, as I am not proficient with python. Maybe you can check the python solution vs. our combined solution on your machine? (Otherwise, the numbers aren't comparable.)

Comment: @Krom Yes, I will check both implementation on my machine. And, probably, I can optimize your solution as well. There's a room for performance boost as I can see.

Comment: @Krom I timed combined solution, got 0.7s, well done, the fastest we got here so far. Running Python (assuming `python` is already installed, on a lot of distros it is by default, if not `sudo apt-get install python` should do it) is a quick thing, just `time python problem10.py`, where problem10.py is [this](https://gist.github.com/AdamStelmaszczyk/d46faa15ba0c6d1432fd1fcbf7cc8a85). With Python 2.7.3 I got 1.2s, with Python 3.4.3 I got 1.5s.

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk I've make it even faster with another approach. See updated answer.

Comment: @Shersh I don't consider my map to be cheating, as it can be expanded into a general purpose Int to Int map. Just add a safe lookup and some rehashing logic.

Comment: @Shersh I applaud your clever solution and upvoted your answer!

Comment: Could you please post the code to your Judy Hashmap solution? I tried to plug Data.Judy into your code and it didn't give me a sub 0.6 second timings.

Comment: @Krom Regarding my code with Judy HashMap — I've just used your solution from gist above. Probably my machine is a little bit faster.

Comment: @Krom Regarding cheating... Well, I thing your algo works better when key set is fixed or when we don't perform inserts and deletes often... And with rehashing it would be slower. But I agree it's fair.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147098/discussion-between-krom-and-shersh).

Comment: I timed your sparse map - 0.2s, it's the fastest Haskell code given, well done. Others were also very helpful, thank you, but I can't split the bounty, so I think you should receive it. Out of curiosity, I [implemented](https://gist.github.com/AdamStelmaszczyk/2e8ab8c1fc57c166c1ba99b6fb9615c4) your idea in C++, I'm just storing everything in one array `S`, it runs in 0.15s.

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk `hashtables` might perform quite badly. But arrays should be close in performance to C++. Though, I'm still surprised they are so close!

Answer (score 4):

First as a baseline, the timings of the existing approaches
on my machine:

1. Original program posted in the question:

   ```
   time stack exec primorig
   95673602693282040

   real    0m4.601s
   user    0m4.387s
   sys     0m0.251s
   ```
2. Second the version using `Data.IntMap.Strict` from
   [here](https://gist.github.com/AdamStelmaszczyk/f9a5d156a752fbe6c71652866fed9770)

   ```
   time stack exec primIntMapStrict
   95673602693282040

   real    0m2.775s
   user    0m2.753s
   sys     0m0.052s
   ```
3. Shershs code with Data.Judy dropped in [here](https://gist.github.com/erwo42/481669257f0e937dc47a4e5b1757a692)

   ```
   time stack exec prim-hash2
   95673602693282040

   real    0m0.945s
   user    0m0.955s
   sys     0m0.028s
   ```
4. Your python solution.

   I compiled it with

   ```
   python -O -m py_compile problem10.py
   ```

   and the timing:

   ```
   time python __pycache__/problem10.cpython-36.opt-1.pyc
   95673602693282040

   real    0m1.163s
   user    0m1.160s
   sys     0m0.003s
   ```
5. Your C++ version:

   ```
   $ g++ -O2 --std=c++11 p10.cpp -o p10
   $ time ./p10
   sum(2000000000) = 95673602693282040

   real    0m0.314s
   user    0m0.310s
   sys     0m0.003s
   ```

I didn't bother to provide a baseline for slow.hs, as I didn't
want to wait for it to complete when run with an argument of
`2*10^9`.

### Subsecond performance

The following program runs in under a second on my machine.

It uses a hand rolled hashmap, which uses closed hashing with
linear probing and uses some variant of knuths hashfunction,
see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664014).

Certainly it is somewhat tailored to the case, as the lookup
function for example expects the searched keys to be present.

Timings:

```
time stack exec prim
95673602693282040

real    0m0.725s
user    0m0.714s
sys     0m0.047s
```

First I implemented my hand rolled hashmap simply to hash
the keys with

```
key `mod` size
```

and selected a size multiple times higher than the expected
input, but the program took 22s or more to complete.

Finally it was a matter of choosing a hash function which was
good for the workload.

Here is the program:

```
import Data.Maybe
import Control.Monad
import Data.Array.IO
import Data.Array.Base (unsafeRead)

type Number = Int

data Map = Map { keys :: IOUArray Int Number
               , values :: IOUArray Int Number
               , size :: !Int 
               , factor :: !Int
               }

newMap :: Int -> Int -> IO Map
newMap s f = do
  k <- newArray (0, s-1) 0
  v <- newArray (0, s-1) 0
  return $ Map k v s f 

storeKey :: IOUArray Int Number -> Int -> Int -> Number -> IO Int
storeKey arr s f key = go ((key * f) `mod` s)
  where
    go :: Int -> IO Int
    go ind = do
      v <- readArray arr ind
      go2 v ind
    go2 v ind
      | v == 0    = do { writeArray arr ind key; return ind; }
      | v == key  = return ind
      | otherwise = go ((ind + 1) `mod` s)

loadKey :: IOUArray Int Number -> Int -> Int -> Number -> IO Int
loadKey arr s f key = s `seq` key `seq` go ((key *f) `mod` s)
  where
    go :: Int -> IO Int
    go ix = do
      v <- unsafeRead arr ix
      if v == key then return ix else go ((ix + 1) `mod` s)

insertIntoMap :: Map -> (Number, Number) -> IO Map
insertIntoMap m@(Map ks vs s f) (k, v) = do
  ix <- storeKey ks s f k
  writeArray vs ix v
  return m

fromList :: Int -> Int -> [(Number, Number)] -> IO Map
fromList s f xs = do
  m <- newMap s f
  foldM insertIntoMap m xs

(!) :: Map -> Number -> IO Number
(!) (Map ks vs s f) k = do
  ix <- loadKey ks s f k
  readArray vs ix

mupdate :: Map -> Number -> (Number -> Number) -> IO ()
mupdate (Map ks vs s fac) i f = do
  ix <- loadKey ks s fac i
  old <- readArray vs ix
  let x' = f old
  x' `seq` writeArray vs ix x'

r' :: Number -> Number
r'  = floor . sqrt . fromIntegral

vs' :: Integral a => a -> a -> [a]
vs' n r = [n `div` i | i <- [1..r]] ++ reverse [1..n `div` r - 1]  

vss' n r = r + n `div` r -1

list' :: Int -> Int -> [Number] -> IO Map
list' s f vs = fromList s f [(i, i * (i + 1) `div` 2 - 1) | i <- vs]

problem10 :: Number -> IO Number
problem10 n = do
      m <- list' (19*vss) (19*vss+7) vs
      nm <- sieve m 2 r vs
      nm ! n
    where vs = vs' n r
          vss = vss' n r
          r  = r' n

sieve :: Map -> Number -> Number -> [Number] -> IO Map
sieve m p r vs | p > r     = return m
               | otherwise = do
                   v1 <- m ! p
                   v2 <- m ! (p - 1)
                   nm <- if v1 > v2 then update m vs p else return m
                   sieve nm (p + 1) r vs

update :: Map -> [Number] -> Number -> IO Map
update m vs p = foldM (decrease p) m $ takeWhile (>= p*p) vs

decrease :: Number -> Map -> Number -> IO Map
decrease p m k = do
  v <- sumOfSieved m k p
  mupdate m k (subtract v)
  return m

sumOfSieved :: Map -> Number -> Number -> IO Number
sumOfSieved m v p = do
  v1 <- m ! (v `div` p)
  v2 <- m ! (p - 1)
  return $ p * (v1 - v2)

main = do { n <- problem10 (2*10^9) ; print n; } -- 2*10^9
```

I am not a professional with hashing and that sort of stuff, so
this can certainly be improved a lot. Maybe we Haskellers should
improve the of the shelf hash maps or provide some simpler ones.

### My hashmap, Shershs code

If I plug my hashmap in Shershs (see answer below) code, see [here](https://gist.github.com/erwo42/a455a80bfe1dac6203204665b71d48b6)
we are even down to

```
time stack exec prim-hash2
95673602693282040

real    0m0.601s
user    0m0.604s
sys     0m0.034s
```

### Why is slow.hs slow?

If you read through the source
for the function `insert` in `Data.HashTable.ST.Basic`, you
will see that it deletes the old key value pair and inserts
a new one. It doesn't look up the "place" for the value and
mutate it, as one might imagine, if one reads that it is
a "mutable" hashtable. Here the hashtable itself is mutable,
so you don't need to copy the whole hashtable for insertion
of a new key value pair, but the value places for the pairs
are not. I don't know if that is the whole story of slow.hs
being slow, but my guess is, it is a pretty big part of it.

### A few minor improvements

So that's the idea I followed while trying to improve
your program the first time.

See, you don't need a mutable mapping from keys to values.
Your key set is fixed. You want a mapping from keys to mutable
places. (Which is, by the way, what you get from C++ by default.)

And so I tried to come up with that. I used `IntMap IORef` from
`Data.IntMap.Strict` and `Data.IORef` first and got a timing
of

```
tack exec prim
95673602693282040

real    0m2.134s
user    0m2.141s
sys     0m0.028s
```

I thought maybe it would help to work with unboxed values
and to get that, I used `IOUArray Int Int` with 1 element
each instead of `IORef` and got those timings:

```
time stack exec prim
95673602693282040

real    0m2.015s
user    0m2.018s
sys     0m0.038s
```

Not much of a difference and so I tried to get rid of bounds
checking in the 1 element arrays by using `unsafeRead` and
`unsafeWrite` and got a timing of

```
time stack exec prim
95673602693282040

real    0m1.845s
user    0m1.850s
sys     0m0.030s
```

which was the best I got using `Data.IntMap.Strict`.

Of course I ran each program multiple times to see if
the times are stable and the differences in run time aren't
just noise.

It looks like these are all just micro-optimizations.

And here is the program that ran fastest for me without using a hand rolled data structure:

```
import qualified Data.IntMap.Strict as M
import Control.Monad
import Data.Array.IO
import Data.Array.Base (unsafeRead, unsafeWrite)

type Number = Int
type Place = IOUArray Number Number
type Map = M.IntMap Place

tupleToRef :: (Number, Number) -> IO (Number, Place)
tupleToRef = traverse (newArray (0,0))

insertRefs :: [(Number, Number)] -> IO [(Number, Place)]
insertRefs = traverse tupleToRef

fromList :: [(Number, Number)] -> IO Map 
fromList xs = M.fromList <$> insertRefs xs

(!) :: Map -> Number -> IO Number
(!) m i = unsafeRead (m M.! i) 0

mupdate :: Map -> Number -> (Number -> Number) -> IO ()
mupdate m i f = do
  let place = m M.! i
  old <- unsafeRead place 0
  let x' = f old
  -- make the application of f strict
  x' `seq` unsafeWrite place 0 x'

r' :: Number -> Number
r'  = floor . sqrt . fromIntegral

vs' :: Integral a => a -> a -> [a]
vs' n r = [n `div` i | i <- [1..r]] ++ reverse [1..n `div` r - 1]  

list' :: [Number] -> IO Map
list' vs = fromList [(i, i * (i + 1) `div` 2 - 1) | i <- vs]

problem10 :: Number -> IO Number
problem10 n = do
      m <- list' vs
      nm <- sieve m 2 r vs
      nm ! n
    where vs = vs' n r
          r  = r' n

sieve :: Map -> Number -> Number -> [Number] -> IO Map
sieve m p r vs | p > r     = return m
               | otherwise = do
                   v1 <- m ! p
                   v2 <- m ! (p - 1)
                   nm <- if v1 > v2 then update m vs p else return m
                   sieve nm (p + 1) r vs

update :: Map -> [Number] -> Number -> IO Map
update m vs p = foldM (decrease p) m $ takeWhile (>= p*p) vs

decrease :: Number -> Map -> Number -> IO Map
decrease p m k = do
  v <- sumOfSieved m k p
  mupdate m k (subtract v)
  return m

sumOfSieved :: Map -> Number -> Number -> IO Number
sumOfSieved m v p = do
  v1 <- m ! (v `div` p)
  v2 <- m ! (p - 1)
  return $ p * (v1 - v2)

main = do { n <- problem10 (2*10^9) ; print n; } -- 2*10^9
```

If you profile that, you see that it spends most of the time in the custom lookup function `(!)`,
don't know how to improve that further. Trying to inline `(!)` with `{-# INLINE (!) #-}`
didn't yield better results; maybe ghc already did this.

Comment: When I am off work, I will post on reddit asking for help. It would be a bit whacky if there wasn't an off-the-shelf library that beats my naive approaches here.

Answer (score 4):

This code of mine evaluates the sum to 2⋅10^9 in 0.3 seconds and the sum to 10^12 (18435588552550705911377) in 19.6 seconds (if given sufficient RAM).

```
import Control.DeepSeq 
import qualified Control.Monad as ControlMonad
import qualified Data.Array as Array
import qualified Data.Array.ST as ArrayST
import qualified Data.Array.Base as ArrayBase

primeLucy :: (Integer -> Integer) -> (Integer -> Integer) -> Integer -> (Integer->Integer)
primeLucy f sf n = g
  where
    r = fromIntegral $ integerSquareRoot n
    ni = fromIntegral n
    loop from to c = let go i = ControlMonad.when (to<=i) (c i >> go (i-1)) in go from

    k = ArrayST.runSTArray $ do
      k <- ArrayST.newListArray (-r,r) $ force $
        [sf (div n (toInteger i)) - sf 1|i<-[r,r-1..1]] ++
        [0] ++
        [sf (toInteger i) - sf 1|i<-[1..r]]
      ControlMonad.forM_ (takeWhile (<=r) primes) $ \p -> do
        l <- ArrayST.readArray k (p-1)
        let q = force $ f (toInteger p)

        let adjust = \i j -> do { v <- ArrayBase.unsafeRead k (i+r); w <- ArrayBase.unsafeRead k (j+r); ArrayBase.unsafeWrite k (i+r) $!! v+q*(l-w) }

        loop (-1)         (-div r p)              $ \i -> adjust i (i*p)
        loop (-div r p-1) (-min r (div ni (p*p))) $ \i -> adjust i (div (-ni) (i*p))
        loop r            (p*p)                   $ \i -> adjust i (div i p)

      return k

    g :: Integer -> Integer
    g m
      | m >= 1 && m <= integerSquareRoot n                       = k Array.! (fromIntegral m)
      | m >= integerSquareRoot n && m <= n && div n (div n m)==m = k Array.! (fromIntegral (negate (div n m)))
      | otherwise = error $ "Function not precalculated for value " ++ show m

primeSum :: Integer -> Integer
primeSum n = (primeLucy id (\m -> div (m*m+m) 2) n) n
```

If your `integerSquareRoot` function is buggy (as reportedly some are), you can replace it here with `floor . sqrt . fromIntegral`.

Explanation:

As the name suggests it is based upon a generalization of the famous method by "Lucy Hedgehog" eventually discovered by the original poster.

It allows you to calculate many sums of the form [image: sum] (with p prime) without enumerating all the primes up to N and in time O(N^0.75).

Its inputs are the function f (i.e., `id` if you want the prime sum), its summatory function over all the integers (i.e., in that case the sum of the first m integers or `div (m*m+m) 2`), and N.

`PrimeLucy` returns a lookup function [image: eq] (with p prime) restricted to certain values of n: [image: values].

Comment: doesn't compile for me, I tried that [here](https://gist.github.com/erwo42/67b15b3643685d9f5e1c63a4748964bf) and tried to compile it with `stack ghc -- -O 2 primediv.hs`. Got Errors like `force`, `primes` not in scope and `($!!)` not in scope.

Comment: Sorry for just copying from my standard library and not including all the imports.  `force` and `($!!)` are from Control.DeepSeq which is included with most distributions.  `primes` is just the list of primes, from whatever source.  I recommend the arithmoi package from Hackage.

Comment: @CarlEdman I [filled the blanks](https://gist.github.com/AdamStelmaszczyk/c433b09c79a54d8b6a3464a758aa15f8) in your code and tried it with n = 2⋅10^9, it ran in 0.3s, impressive. Could you please describe your approach?

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk Happy to.  Will do so as edit of appendix of my post.

Comment: I think I wasn't precise enough with the previous question, sorry. I understand how Lucy's algorithm work. What I would like to understand is why your Haskell code is so fast and is it the same method as Shersh's "my code + my map" that achieved 0.2s? E.g. "I used 2 mutable arrays, in the first one I store x... that is the same/not the same as Shersh, the difference is y".

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk Beyond the algorithm, there is no magic to the performance beyond the usual trial-by-error hand-tuning.  It probably started with something like Shersh's and then was transformed bit-by-bit. Things that helped: Using a single mutable array; just modifying the array on each iteration, rather than copying to a new one, by performing the updates in careful order; unsafeRead/Write; custom inner loop rather than forM_; forcing results early via '$!!' and 'force'.

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk Also thanks for fixing up my TeX!  I keep forgetting which forums allow which syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Try this and let me know how fast it is:

```
-- sum of primes

import Control.Monad (forM_, when)
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.Array.ST
import Data.Array.Unboxed

sieve :: Int -> UArray Int Bool
sieve n = runSTUArray $ do
    let m = (n-1) `div` 2
        r = floor . sqrt $ fromIntegral n
    bits <- newArray (0, m-1) True
    forM_ [0 .. r `div` 2 - 1] $ \i -> do
        isPrime <- readArray bits i
        when isPrime $ do
            let a = 2*i*i + 6*i + 3
                b = 2*i*i + 8*i + 6
            forM_ [a, b .. (m-1)] $ \j -> do
                writeArray bits j False
    return bits

primes :: Int -> [Int]
primes n = 2 : [2*i+3 | (i, True) <- assocs $ sieve n]

main = do
    print $ sum $ primes 1000000
```

You can run it on [ideone](http://ideone.com/D8aBnJ). My algorithm is the Sieve of Eratosthenes, and it should be quite fast for small *n*. For *n* = 2,000,000,000, the array size may be a problem, in which case you will need to use a segmented sieve. See [my blog](https://programmingpraxis.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/primenumbers.pdf) for more information about the Sieve of Eratosthenes. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10249801/448810) for information about a segmented sieve (but not in Haskell, unfortunately).

Comment: I tried it with n = 2⋅10^9 to compare to other implementations, 71 seconds. From what I understand, the time complexity of segmented sieve is the same as non-segmented one. I appreciate that in reality, the locality of reference can improve the speed in segmented version, however my feeling is that it will be slower than _sub-linear_ algorithm presented by Lucy_Hedgehog. My question is about optimizing Haskell code implementing Lucy's algorithm, I clarified the question now a bit, I can see how it could be a bit confusing, sorry. Nice blog, I will read it, I especially like your essays.

Comment: The segmented sieve has the same big-oh time complexity, but will be very much faster due to locality of reference. Thank you for your nice comments about my blog.